# Showing information of several layers of GeoJSON request to GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, leaflet

Always enters the error function and shows me the alert 'what happen?'.

This is the piece of code that causes problems:

```
map.addEventListener('click',onMapClick);
function onMapClick(e)
{
    var latlngStr = '('+ e.latlng.lat.toFixed(3) + ", " + e.latlng.lng.toFixed(3)+')';
    var BBOX = map.getBounds()._southWest.lng + ", " + map.getBounds()._southWest.lat + ", " + map.getBounds()._northEast.lng + ", " + map.getBounds()._northEast.lat;
    var WIDTH = map.getSize().x;
    var HEIGHT = map.getSize().y;   
    var X = map.layerPointToContainerPoint(e.layerPoint).x.toFixed(0);
    var Y = map.layerPointToContainerPoint(e.layerPoint).y.toFixed(0);
    URL = 'http://192.168.60.55:9090/geoserver/ems/wms?request=GetFeatureInfo&service=WMS&version=1.1.1&info_format=application/json&exceptions=application/vnd.ogc.se_xml&layers=ems:tblsevilla,ems:tblmanz,ems:tblcarre&styles=&srs=EPSG%3A4326&format=image%2Fpng&bbox='+ BBOX + '&width='+ WIDTH +'&height='+ HEIGHT + '&query_layers=ems:tblsevilla,ems:tblmanz,ems:tblcarre&feature_count=20&x='+ X +'&y='+ Y;

    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        if (feature.properties && feature.properties.PERIMETRO)
        layer.bindPopup("Perimetro: "+feature.properties.PERIMETRO);
        }
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: URL,
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            alert("2");
            L.geoJson(response, {
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature
            }).addTo(map);
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            alert('what happen?');
        }
    });
}
```

I'm a Leaflet and GeoServer beginner.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing an opening semicolon.

In your `if` statement inside of `onEachFeature` it looks like you've intended to include curly braces around the `layer.bindPopup` statement, but you've only included the closing curly brace.

Here is your code as I think you intended it:

```
map.addEventListener('click',onMapClick);
function onMapClick(e)
{
    var latlngStr = '('+ e.latlng.lat.toFixed(3) + ", " + e.latlng.lng.toFixed(3)+')';
    var BBOX = map.getBounds()._southWest.lng + ", " + map.getBounds()._southWest.lat + ", " + map.getBounds()._northEast.lng + ", " + map.getBounds()._northEast.lat;
    var WIDTH = map.getSize().x;
    var HEIGHT = map.getSize().y;   
    var X = map.layerPointToContainerPoint(e.layerPoint).x.toFixed(0);
    var Y = map.layerPointToContainerPoint(e.layerPoint).y.toFixed(0);
    URL = 'http://192.168.60.55:9090/geoserver/ems/wms?request=GetFeatureInfo&service=WMS&version=1.1.1&info_format=application/json&exceptions=application/vnd.ogc.se_xml&layers=ems:tblsevilla,ems:tblmanz,ems:tblcarre&styles=&srs=EPSG%3A4326&format=image%2Fpng&bbox='+ BBOX + '&width='+ WIDTH +'&height='+ HEIGHT + '&query_layers=ems:tblsevilla,ems:tblmanz,ems:tblcarre&feature_count=20&x='+ X +'&y='+ Y;


    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        if (feature.properties && feature.properties.PERIMETRO) {
            layer.bindPopup("Perimetro: "+feature.properties.PERIMETRO);
        }
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: URL,
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            alert("2");
            L.geoJson(response, {
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature
            }).addTo(map);
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            alert('what happen?');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer but that is not the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should make a `GET` request instead of a `POST`. For these cases you can use the jquery function [getjson](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

```
$.getJSON(URL, success, error);

function success (response) {
    alert("2");
    L.geoJson(response, {
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(map);
};

function error (req, status, error) {
    alert('what happen?');
};
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I do not work, the function does not enter either success or an error.

Comment: Are you sure that getFeatureInfo is returning the right value. Can you post what the browser shows when you open URL in the browser

Comment: I put the beginning:{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"tblsevilla.1","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[7112.765334135802,1984.4545757051674],....

Comment: I make a typo in the code i put URL within quotes

Comment: URL is a variable. It goes without quotes